# could not send message using net send

Tags: java, network-programming

I have done the following java program using **net send**.It says message sent successfully, but i couldn't see the message.Here is my code

```
  import java.io.*;
  import java.net.*;
  class sample{
   public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
    {
    try{
        Runtime r=Runtime.getRuntime();
        Process p=null;
        String msg;
        String TRIP;
        String cmd;
        BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        System.out.println("Enter ip address of remote host");
        TRIP=br.readLine();
        System.out.println("Enter the msg to be sent to remote host");
        msg=br.readLine();
        cmd="net send"+TRIP+""+msg;
        p=r.exec(cmd);
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        System.out.println("msg soc sent to the sysytem");
        }catch(Exception e){
          System.out.println(e);
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: What versión of Windows do you have? In Windows 7 there is no "net send" anymore, you shuold use the "msg" commnad instead.

Comment: i am using windows xp

Comment: It says it sent successfully (if you mean your print in the code) because you do not have any error checking at all.

Answer (score 1):

You need more spaces in your string:

```
 cmd="net send "+TRIP+" "+msg;
```

Otherwise the IPaddress (or whatever string was given) will be directly after `send` in the resulting string.